# High order function toggling a predicate method

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to toggle a predicate method in combination with the [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html) interface?

```
require 'prime'

(1..10).select(&:prime?)
# => [2, 3, 5, 7]

# Toggling the prime? predicate?
(1..10).select(not(&:prime?))
# SyntaxError: (irb):3: syntax error, unexpected &, expecting ')'
```

Concretely I need another predicate, that returns true if all element doesn't fulfill the custom predicate.

```
# concrete example
set.all?(not(:&custom_predicate?))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case [`Enumerable#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) method can be used:

```
(1..10).reject(&:prime?)
```

If you need to toggle a custom predicate in combination with `any?` and `all?` method, it can be implemented according to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)`:

`any?(&:predicate?) == !all? { |obj| !obj.predicate? }`

For example:

```
require 'prime'

(1..10).any?(&:prime?) == !(1..10).all? { |num| !num.prime? }
```

Comment: I moved my comment to the question to make my choice reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, two ways:

- use `reject`

  ```
  (1..10).reject(&:prime?)
  ```
- expand the block

  ```
  (1..10).select { |n| !n.prime? }
  ```

Comment: Actually, that's totally doable, with a bit of code. :)

Comment: Oh yeah, sure. I meant there is no out-of-the-box solution

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. Stdlib is huuuge and there are many dark corners :)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just implement your negator. Don't remember if such thing exists in the stdlib.

```
require 'prime'

def nay(&proc)
  ->(obj) { !proc.call(obj) }  
end

puts (1..10).select(&nay(&:prime?))
# >> 1
# >> 4
# >> 6
# >> 8
# >> 9
# >> 10
```

Can't use the word "not" here, it's a keyword.